# Concatenation of numpy arrays on condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I was wondering if there was a numpy-way to concatenate 2 arrays of different len (a and b) along an axis based according to a boolean one of (len a + b)

I already can make this array with python list comprehension (according to the boolean) or with creating multiple new arrays (2).

## Simple Example:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(3)
b = np.arange(3, 8)
a_b = np.arange(8) < 3

def np_or_not(a_b, a, b, axis=-1):
    axis = axis // len(a_b)
    aligned_a = np.take(a, np.cumsum(a_b) - 1, axis=axis)
    aligned_b = np.take(b, np.cumsum(~a_b) - 1, axis=axis)
    return np.where(a_b, aligned_a, aligned_b)

assert (np_or_not(a_b, a, b) == np.arange(8)).all()
```

## N-D case :

### Initialization

```py
axis = 2
a = np.random.rand(10, 20, 4)
b = np.random.rand(10, 20, 9)
a_b = np.array([True] * a.shape[axis] + [False] * b.shape[axis])
np.random.shuffle(a_b)
```

### Checks (formats)

```py
assert len(a.shape) == len(b.shape)
assert all(a.shape[ax] == b.shape[ax] for ax in range(len(a.shape)) if ax != axis)
assert len(a_b) == (a.shape[axis] + b.shape[axis])
assert sum(a_b) == a.shape[axis]
assert sum(~a_b) == b.shape[axis]
```

### Checks results

```py
result = np_or_not(a_b, a, b, axis=-1)

assert result.shape == tuple(l if ax != axis else len(a_b) for ax, l in enumerate(a.shape))

a_b_indexes = [0, 0]
for index, truth in enumerate(a_b):
    assert (result[..., index] == (a if truth else b)[..., a_b_indexes[1 - truth]]).all(), index
    a_b_indexes[1 - truth] += 1
```

**EDIT** : Thanks for the reply, I replaced stacking by concatenate and provided a N-D case example.

Comment: Can you use a more generic sample, say `a = np.random.randint(10,100,(3)); 
b = np.random.randint(10,100,(5))` and similarly for `a_b` and show us the expected output? Or would the input arrays be specifically those as in the given sample?

Comment: Also, you are not actually stacking your arrays, but concatenating them. Please specify whether you want to stack or concatenate.

Comment: Thanks for the replies : I replace stacking by concatenate.

And added a random N-D example.